# Excel Run Time Error ( Formatting Issue

Tags: excel, vba

I regularly format a worksheet with payroll data. It has the same layout each time, but is of different length depending on how many employees worked that week. I'm having trouble creating a macro that will work for the different number of rows. The error is "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" which occurs on line 22. My guess is that this occurs because it is referring to the specific worksheet and not simply what is open. Any help is much appreciated!

https://pastebin.com/embed_js/VV6d6De8">

```
' WLM_2 Macro
'

'
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:C").Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Columns("B:B").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WeeklyLaborHours (5)").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WeeklyLaborHours (5)").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WeeklyLaborHours (5)").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:V371")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to specifically work on the ActiveSheet and not a predetermined (and hard-coded) worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your suspicion is correct. If you have a worksheet other than `WeeklyLaborHours (5)` selected when you run the macro, it will fail. If don't specify the worksheet when you call a range, it will default to the selected worksheet. The code below should correct the error, but it assumes you want to do all the stuff before the sort field commands on the active worksheet rather than on `WeeklyLaborHours (5)` specifically.

```
Public Sub WLM_2()
'WLM_2 Macro
'
    Dim wsWLH5 As Worksheet

    Set wsWLH5 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WeeklyLaborHours (5)")
'
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("A:C").Select
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Columns("B:B").Select
    With wsWLH5.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=wsWLH5.Range("B1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
        Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange wsWLH5.Range("A2:V371")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've removed your Select and hard-coded worksheet references and concentrated the code on the ActiveWindow and ActiveSheet.

```
Sub WLM_2()
    ' WLM_2 Macro
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
        .FreezePanes = True
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Columns("C:F").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
        .Columns("A:C").AutoFit
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 21))
            .Sort Key1:=.Columns(2), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                  Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlNo
        End With
        .Columns("B:B").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

I've also aggregated the four successive column delete commands into a single delete and reduced the .Sort command down to what you actually require.